# Cannot install postgis2_94 on Centos 7.5

Tags: yum, postgresql

I am trying to install postgis2_94 on CentOS 7.5 with the following command (having already installed postgresql94 ):

```
yum install postgresql94-server postgresql94-devel postgis2_94 postgis2_94-docs postgis2_94-utils pgrouting
```

But, I get the following error:

> Transaction check error:   file /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/shp2pgsql-gui
>   conflicts between attempted installs of
>   postgis24_94-2.4.4-2.rhel7.x86_64 and
>   postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64   file
>   /usr/pgsql-9.4/lib/liblwgeom.so conflicts between attempted installs
>   of postgis24_94-2.4.4-2.rhel7.x86_64 and
>   postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64   file
>   /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/address_standardizer.control conflicts
>   between attempted installs of postgis24_94-2.4.4-2.rhel7.x86_64 and
>   postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64   file
>   /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/address_standardizer.sql conflicts
>   between attempted installs of postgis24_94-2.4.4-2.rhel7.x86_64 and
>   postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64   file
>   /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/address_standardizer_data_us.control
>   conflicts between attempted installs of
>   postgis24_94-2.4.4-2.rhel7.x86_64 and
>   postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64   file
>   /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/address_standardizer_data_us.sql
>   conflicts between attempted installs of
>   postgis24_94-2.4.4-2.rhel7.x86_64 and
>   postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64   file
>   /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/postgis.control conflicts between
>   attempted installs of postgis24_94-2.4.4-2.rhel7.x86_64 and
>   postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64   file
>   /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/postgis_sfcgal.control conflicts
>   between attempted installs of postgis24_94-2.4.4-2.rhel7.x86_64 and
>   postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64   file
>   /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder.control
>   conflicts between attempted installs of
>   postgis24_94-2.4.4-2.rhel7.x86_64 and
>   postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64   file
>   /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder.sql conflicts
>   between attempted installs of postgis24_94-2.4.4-2.rhel7.x86_64 and
>   postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64   file
>   /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/postgis_topology.control conflicts
>   between attempted installs of postgis24_94-2.4.4-2.rhel7.x86_64 and
>   postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64
>   Error Summary
>   `-------------`

How can I solve that?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  I have a similar issue with postgis2_95.

Comment: I don't really remember how I fixed this :(, I might be able to find something in my docs though.

Comment: It's ok.  I solved this by moving to Ubuntu - all installed w/o conflicts, etc.  Too many headaches with CentOS all the time - cannot afford any more wasted days with it.